# Linux kernel tune in Google Container Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed a redis container to Google Container Engine and get the following warnings.

```
10:M 01 Mar 05:01:46.140 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
```

I know to correct the warning I need executing 

`echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`

I tried that in container but does not help.

How to solve this warning in Google Container Engine?

As I understand, my `pods` are running on the `node`, and the `node` is a VM private for me only?  So I ssh to the `node` and modify the kernel directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you own the nodes and can ssh into them and modify them as you need.

Comment: Will my modification conflict or overridden by Google Container Engine?  I see Google Container Engine deployed other containers there

Comment: It won't persist across node upgrades (because the nodes will be replaced) but otherwise won't be overridden by Google Container Engine. I don't know if it will conflict, as running with that particular kernel configuration isn't enabled by default, but the risk seems pretty low.